# Update CSS Attribute of Non-React Dom Element from React app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom

I'm creating a react-based app that will function within a Wordpress page. The app is self-contained for the most part, but I'd like to be able to show/hide a div element on the page that is not part of the react app. If I were doing this with jQuery I could just do:

```
jQuery(".image_column").css("display","none");
```

But since I want to call this from a function at a certain point in the react app I'm getting tripped up. It seems like a straightforward thing to do but I'm stumped. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly one on my part. The answer was to add "window."  Once I did that everything worked. I'll leave this question up in case someone else has a temporary issue of seeing the simple answer!

In my case, with Wordpress, I needed to reference jQuery and not $. So it looks like:

```
window.jQuery(".entry-content").css("display","none");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```js
document.querySelector(".image_column").style.display = "none"
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I was just coming on to answer this myself. window.jQuery(".entry-content").css("display","none"); Silly, just needed to add "window"